# File split and write to multiple files

Tags: java, java-8, apache-camel

Could you please and Help me on this. Consider following and it's in single text file say `chines.txt`

```
line no:1(AP9000)
2<CAT-DOG FILE>
3<DATA>
4<DATE=19NOV14>
5GOOG2402l 19NOV14 05:00 2.0
6APL2402h  19NOV14 05:00 6.0
7IBM2401w  19NOV14 05:00 586.0
8<END>
Line no: 9 (NNNN)
Line number:10    
11(AP9000)
12<CAT-DOG FILE>
13<DATA>
14<DATE=19NOV14>
15GOOG2402l 19NOV14 05:00 2.0
16APL2402h  19NOV14 05:00 6.0
17IBM2401w  19NOV14 05:00 586.0
18<END>
19(NNNN)
```

How do I split above one into two files. meaning from (AP900) to (NNNN) from line number 1 through 9 goes to `one.txt` and from (AP900) to (NNNN) from line number 11 through 19 goes to `two.txt`. Line numbers are given 1 trough 19 for example.

How can I split into two files either Java 8 or Apache Camel?

Java 8 Code to Read this file

```
try {

       List<String> stringList =Files.lines(Paths.get("chines.txt"))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
                stringList.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not found file");
        }
```

Comment: Is this a real example of the file? If not, could you put one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is not clear and some requirements seem weird (why would you want to create files like `one.txt`, and not `1.txt`)? But it's just a small finger exercise. Maybe this could help?

```
// Iterator<String> fileNames = Arrays.asList("one.txt", "two.txt", "three.txt", "four.txt", "five.txt", "six.txt", "seven.txt").iterator();
int i = 1;
Pattern start = Pattern.compile("\\(AP9000\\)");
Pattern end = Pattern.compile("\\(NNNN\\)");
boolean reading = false;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
Iterator<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("c:/d/test.txt")).iterator();
while (lines.hasNext() /* && fileNames.hasNext() */) {
    String line = lines.next();
    Matcher startMatcher = start.matcher(line);
    if (startMatcher.find()) {
        reading = true;
        fos = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(i++) + ".txt"/*fileNames.next()*/);
    }
    if (reading) {
        fos.write(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        fos.write('\n');
    }
    Matcher endMatcher = end.matcher(line);
    if (endMatcher.find()) {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
        reading = false;
    }
}
if (fos != null) {
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: Firstly I would like Thank you **steffen**, for solution which you have provided. Thing is There would be more lines with in same file (chimes.txt-2000 MB). Then files would be named like 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and so on.

Comment: those sequence of files(1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and so on) would be transformed using apache Camel and Kafka

Comment: @sekhar So yes, if you want files like `1.txt`, you'd just use a counter, like `new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(i++) + ".txt");`.

Comment: counter not working , like new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(i++) + ".txt"); Could you please assist me on this steffen

Comment: files are not created like 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt and so on. While I am using `new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(i++) + ".txt");`

Comment: @sekhar I don't understand. You can run the program without error messages and there are no files created? That doesn't make sense. It works here...

Comment: It's okay steffen, no problrm

Comment: @sekhar Just to mention: I just tried it and it indeed works. Compare your code with the last edit above.